# Is it possible to convert window into tab?

Tags: macos, finder, safari, tabs

I can drag a tab out of window, and it becomes independent window in Safari, Finder and other apps that support tabs. Is it possible to reverse this operation, convert window into tab by dragging it to another window?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to drag a tab - Safari won't let you drag an entire window into another one.  You can hit ⌘T to create a new empty tab (thus making the tab interface visible), then drag your original tab to the other window.

Comment: @nicael I believe you _can_. You don't need to create a new tab for the tab bar to show up. I believe somewhere in the menu items at the top you can check 'show tab bar permanently'. If you've done that, 1 tab will show up. You can drag that to another window, and the original window should disappear.

Comment: 11684 is correct; you can drag a single tab to another Safari window.  The feedback for the drag operation is kind of confusing. There's no visual indication that you are dragging until you move the pointer beyond the title bar, toolbar, and favorites bar. Note that you have to drag the tab bar (not the Window's title bar), so the tab bar has to be visible.

Comment: In the current beta of Yosemite you can also drag the URL, see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147523/how-to-drag-the-last-safari-tab-to-another-window I don’t think that this was possible in previous versions of Safari.

Comment: Just to add information to 11684 & GraniteRobert 's answers, in OS X 10.10.5 the location at which you have to start dragging is the small horizontal space below the URL bar. The area is very small though, you may need to experiment to get it right. This assumes that View --> Show Tab Bar is not active (the default when there is only one tab in a window).

Comment: @11684 HOLD mouse on the icon in the toolbar and drag (or just drag directories) to the + icon on the right of tab bar in the other window, then drop. It will create a NEW tab in the other window with the path you dropped.

Answer (score 19):

Go to Window → Merge All Windows. In Safari, this merges other windows into the currently active window. In Finder, this merges the current windows into other window.

Alternatively, you can show the tab bar with View → Show Tab Bar. This lets you drag the tab when only one tab in a window is open.

Comment: THX for some tips!

Answer (score 5):

You can just hit <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to make the tab bar visible in any finder window. This allows you to drag the current window as a tab into any other finder window.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just drag the tab of the new window in the right location of the old window, and it is done. In this way you can also drag-n-drop tabs of safari between different open windows.

I know it works in Chrome like this

Comment: I want to convert independent window into tab.

Comment: Tabs can be visible with just one tab open. Then my method works. But then again, that is for Chrome (on Mac OS X)

Comment: I repeat: I have independent window. I want to drag it to another window so as it will become tab of last window.

Comment: I tried to make a screenshot of the progress, but Im on linux and  it should be clear. Drag the tab from one window to another. If the tabs aren't visible, use the ⌘T technique from jdselStrother's answer

Comment: This is for Chrome. Finder and Safari both hide their tab bars when there is only one tab open.

Comment: So then create an empty tab, and close it when the tab is moved

Comment: +1 for this answer.  It's correct for Safari (as well as Chrome).

Comment: @GraniteRobert Unfortunatly it is not.

Comment: @Mathias711 That was already mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside ahh, I did read it at the time you answered it, but now Im home and try to merge tabs myself in safari and stumbled across the option

Comment: @nicael: Using OS X 10.9.3 and Safari 7.0.4, it does work. I used to think it didn't work, until I saw Mathias711's answer.  You can drag a window's only tab bar to another window.  The first window vanishes, and the content appears in a new tab in the second window. Notes: 1) The tab bar must be visible in the first window. 2) You have to drag the _tab_ bar, not the _title_ bar. 3) There may be no visual feedback for the drag at first, so it seems like it's not working. A fast drag gives feedback after less motion than a slow drag.

Comment: @GraniteRobert a! Yes, sorry and giving +1 to the answer, I just misunderstood it at tbe beginning.

Comment: In Chrome it reloads the tab. In case of Google Hangout the tab becomes blank.

Comment: @Mathias711 you can also type `CMD` + `Shift` + `T` with a single window open to show the tabbar. Dragging the tabbar (right below the title bar) will then add the tab to the other window and close the former window immediately after.